# PHP Update with Curl Please

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to update my API with an update curl function but am struggling to work out why it isn't working

The areas where it may be wrong is `key($id)` I want it to 
extract the ID column based on the key value for the ID array.

`$URL` I want to create the URL based on the const variables plus the resource name plus the value of the ID array that has been passed through `rawurlencode`.

So far this is my update code, but am wondering what area is wrong.
I can provide more info if needed and appreciate any help, thanks

```
<?php 
function update(array $id,array $vaules, $resourcename)
    $jsonData = json_encode($vaules);
    key($id);
    $url = DOMAIN.FOLDER.APIPATH.$resourcename.rawurlencode("/".$id);   
    $ch = curl_init($url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array ('content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,PUT);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$jsonData);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_getinfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}
```

Comment: What do you get in getinfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `key()` returns the current key in an array (according to the internet pointer). Right now you're not doing anything with it, you're calling the function and not assigning it anywhere.

Did you mean to write: `rawurlencode("/".key($id).$vaules);`?

As your code is right now, assuming `$id` is an array, you're trying to convert an array into a string, which I doubt is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply with key i want it to extract the id coloum based on the key vaule, okay so maybe i need to assign it within the url. Also nope i think this is pasrt of the issues i have updated it without vaules.

Comment: You need to fix `rawurlencode()`, `$id` is an array, not a string. Can you show a `var_dump()` of what `$id` is?

Comment: Hi $id the primary key, eg: id=Barth%2C+John&idColumn=Author_Name           i am unsure on how var_dump works

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The function definition shows it's an array, `update(array $id ...)`, it's not a string.

Comment: Hi sorry yep  id is an array

Comment: sorry please advise me again what to test

Comment: Without knowing what's in `$id`, it's impossible to fix. You need to do a `var_dump($id)` and post the contents here.

Comment: Okay sorry where do i view the var_dump result?

Comment: Sorry heres the var dump string 'Barth, John' (length=11)

Comment: If you are getting that as a result from `var_dump($id)`, then you have an error in your function definition, since `$id` is not an array, it's a string. Which also means you don't need `key()` and can just put `rawurlencode("/".$id)` as is.